# Exclude base directory (and also file name) from full path

Tags: c#, string, path, directory

Say I have this input (The base directory) as string (of course there can be different-longer-path):

```
c:\Projects\ (could be also c:\Projects)
```

and this input (Files in subdirectories) as string:

```
c:\Projects\bin\file1.exe
c:\Projects\src\folder\file2.exe
```

What is the best way to get such strings:

```
bin
src\folder
```

That is, from the full paths I want to exclude tha base directory(that is given) and filenames.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow a logic like;

```
string root = @"c:\Projects";
string path = @"c:\Projects\src\folder\file2.exe";

path = path.Replace(root, "").Replace(Path.GetFileName(path), "").Trim('\\');

Console.WriteLine(path);
```

1. Replace this base directory and file name (with extension) to empty string.
2. Trim the `\` character possible end of `bin\` or `src\folder\`

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
string s = @"c:\Projects\bin\file1.exe";
var split_s = s.Split(new char[]{'\\'}).Skip(2);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(@"\", split_s.Take(split_s.Count() - 1).ToArray()));
```

[Example IDEONE](http://ideone.com/J6OMyN)

This splits the string at the slashes, skips over the first two entries (the drive and projects folder) and then takes the next X number of directories - not including the filename. And then joins it back together.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following static methods to calculate a relative parent path for a given one:

```
    public static string GetRelativeParentPath(string basePath, string path)
    {
        return GetRelativePath(basePath, Path.GetDirectoryName(path));
    }

    public static string GetRelativePath(string basePath, string path)
    {
        // normalize paths
        basePath = Path.GetFullPath(basePath);
        path = Path.GetFullPath(path);

        // same path case
        if (basePath == path)
            return string.Empty;

        // path is not contained in basePath case
        if (!path.StartsWith(basePath))
            return string.Empty;

        // extract relative path
        if (basePath[basePath.Length - 1] != Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)
        {
            basePath += Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
        }

        return path.Substring(basePath.Length);
    }
```

And this is the way you can use it:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string basePath = @"c:\Projects\";
        string file1 = @"c:\Projects\bin\file1.exe";
        string file2 = @"c:\Projects\src\folder\file2.exe";

        Console.WriteLine(GetRelativeParentPath(basePath, file1));
        Console.WriteLine(GetRelativeParentPath(basePath, file2));
    }
```

Output:

```
bin
src\folder
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Regex as it is matter of Strings,

```
   string ResultString = null;
 try {
    ResultString = Regex.Match(SubjectString, "c:\\\\Projects\\\\(?<data>.*?)\\\\(\\w|\\d)*     (\\.exe|.png|jpeg)",
    RegexOptions.Multiline).Groups["data"].Value;
 } catch (ArgumentException ex) {
// Syntax error in the regular expression
 }
```

You can exclude or include more file types like i added png and jpeg.Drawback is that initial part of string must start from C:/Project